# How to serialize extra fields. Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to return extra data for the "following_user" but I'm getting returned the data for the "user" instance

The View to get Users following list:

```
class UsersFollowing(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_class = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_class = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = FollowingSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.GET.get('user_id')
        obj = Follow.objects.filter(user=user)

        return obj
```

the Serializer:

```
class FollowingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avi_pic = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_avi_pic')
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_username')
    first_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_first_name')
    last_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_last_name')

    def get_username(self, obj):
        username = obj.following_user.username
        return username
    
    def get_first_name(self, obj):
        first_name = obj.following_user.first_name
        return first_name
    
    def get_last_name(self, obj):
        last_name = obj.following_user.last_name
        return last_name

    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = "__all__"
```

my Follow model:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "User", related_name="follower", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following_user = models.ForeignKey(
        "User", related_name="following", blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_followed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    avi_pic = models.ImageField(
        _('avi_pic'), upload_to=aviFile, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your naming of foreign key fields is not good. It is often better not to add the trailing the word `id`. Then the Django ORM will automatically adds the field named `user_id`.

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "User", related_name="follower", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following_user = models.ForeignKey(
        "User", related_name="following", blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_followed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And then in the serializer, you could set the serializer of the `User` model.

```
class FollowingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only = True)
    following_user = UserSerializer(read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = "__all__"
```